# Search in PHP did not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm not really good in PHP and AJAX I need your help guys for this. A cannot get a simple search using PHP and AJAX here's my code guys. The load_data function in AJAX was functioning but I'm not sure if it calls the .php function in my files but the files are not separated.

**Here's my HTML**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TESTING</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br />
      <h2 align="center">TESTING</h2>
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
          <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**And here's my AJAX script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  load_data();

  function load_data(query) {
    //alert('testing');
    $.ajax({
      url: "functions.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
    // alert(query);
  }

  $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    //alert(search);
    if (search != '') {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      load_data();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**And here's my PHP**

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "erpts_system");

$output = '';
if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
  $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR middlename LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR email LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR username LIKE '%".$search."%'
  ";
} else {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM users ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table bordered">
       <tr>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>City</th>
         <th>Postal Code</th>
         <th>Country</th>
       </tr>
    ';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
        <tr>
          <td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["middlename"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo $output;
} else {
  echo 'Data Not Found';
}
?>
```

Comment: do you really program like that? no indentation? makes life hard, don't you think? Anyway, anything in your browser **developer** tools console or network tabs to indicate an error?

Comment: Try it without the ajax, if it works then check your developer console.

Comment: `$_POST["query"]` that to me is failing since your input doesn't match the name attribute for it `name="search_text"` and error reporting would have thrown you something about it. I'm guessing your `else{...}` is kicking in instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `data:{query:query}` suggests otherwise, the code isn't submitting a form at all (i.e. the `name` of the input is irrelevant) - it's POSTing a request

Comment: @JaromandaX i'm sorry sir but in my code i have indentation. but when i copied it here, it change. hmm no sir there's no error in the browser

Comment: check the AJAX post parameters and return value in the browser developer tools network tab

Comment: @JaromandaX i've put this after success in ajax `"testing"` and `$data =$_POST['data']; echo "testing";` and in the developer tools network the time is pending. sorry but i don't know the meaning of this sir/ma'am.

Comment: I'm asking you to use your browsers **developer** tools to see what is being sent and received by the browser, to check that it is as expected - if you don't know what that means, then I can't help any more

Comment: @JaromandaX i know the developer tools sir but the time side for the css and js are pending

Comment: I don't know what that means or has to do with debugging your code, sorry, I'm out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the code and launched it on my local machine, its working just perfectly. I think your problem comes from linking your js file. I haven't seen a script tag linking your js file. If you don't intend to use an external script i would suggest you insert your javascript code at the end of your document like this

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TESTING</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <h2 align="center">TESTING</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
                <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //load_data();

            function load_data(query) {
                //alert('testing');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "functions.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                });
                // alert(query);
            }

            $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
                var search = $(this).val();
                //alert(search);
                if (search != '') {
                    load_data(search);
                } else {
                    load_data();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Please note how i commented the load function you called just before the function declaration. Ensure that the php file is in the same directory with the php file containing this code. All the best

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my setup...similar to yours...

```
$.ajax({
url:'checkin_ajax.php',
type:'POST',
data:'id=' + id + '&address=' + address2 + '&latitude=' + latitude2 + '&longitude=' + longitude2 + '&business=' + businessname2,
success: function(msg){

    if($.trim(msg) == "failed"){

    alert('You must be logged in');

    }
    else {


    alert('Check in successful');
    /*
    var datad = $(msg).text();
    console.log(datad);
    var resultstring = datad.replace(',]',']');
    var JsonParseData = JSON.parse(resultstring);
    */



    }

}//ends success code




});//ends ajax
```

Comment: Plus I dont think you are sending your data correctly. Your also calling the load_data() without no data in the input field on page load.